# UFT Run Results Viewer does not open test results

Tags: test-report, hp-uft, uft-12.52

## TLDR

`HP Run Results Viewer` of UFT 12.52 shows `Could not load run result.` message on opening test result.

## About UFT 12.52 Results viewing

UFT 12.52 has two possibility for results viewing:

**1. Inside HP UFT window** as a separate tab

[image]

**2. In Run Results Viewer**

[image]

## The problem. Can only view last result

I can not open test result I want (just the last ones and only in `UFT` tool, not in `HP Run Results Viewer`)

---

**a)** When I try to open any test result in `Run Results Viewer` with option `Results XML file` (even those which were able to open in UFT Result View, see pic 1) there is an error "Could not load run result."

[image]

---

**b)** When I try to open any test result in `Run Results Viewer` with option `Test name` there are no `Run names` displayed (but they do exist):

[image]

---

**c)** My scripts do change results folder (this could be the reason as it mentioned in the post [HP Run results viewer error - Could not load run result.](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/HP-Run-results-viewer-error-Could-not-load-run-result/td-p/6776344))

```
Please review if there are functions in your test scripts (or test calls to other scripts) that touch the resultsdirectory,  there has been issues where the test cases have code lines to manipulate the results directory to delete data from them. Based on your description,  it only happens with some test instance,  not all test cases; which indicates that those test instances are from the same test case which have code or functions with code lines that touches the resultsdirectory.
```

I created new test in UFT 12.52 which does just simply `a = 2 + 2`, run it, tried to open results in `HP Run Results Viewer`, the result was the same `Could not load run result.` message ([the test does not even involve objects](http://www.learnqtp.com/forums/Thread-Reporter-unable-to-load-results-when-objects-are-involved) not in Descriptive Programming neither in Object Repository style). So this is not the reason.

**d)** Can only open last results in HP UFT Result Viewer (internal) but as you can see there is even no specification which result you are opening (Res1, Res2,3,...??? just name of the test):

[image]

**e)** Performed clean uninstall of UFT ([download link](https://qtpuninstaller.codeplex.com/downloads/get/599198)) than installed again but the result was the same. (**Warning:** java objects recognition was broken after the clean uninstall)

**f)** Removed `HP Run Results Viewer` (by running reinstallation of UTF, selected `Change` and deselected Results Viewer), run test in UFT and result is still shown in internal results viewer.

**g)** `HP Run Results Viewer 12.52` opens run results created by QTP 11.00 just fine, still having problems with 12.52 test results

## Question

How can I open any run result (not only recent) in `HP UFT Result Viewer (internal)` or in `Run Results Viewer`?

Comment: It can be related to the installation of the Run Result Viewer, the software has the permission to read where the result files are stored? Have you try to open the result of a Run after opening Run Result Viewer and connecting it to ALM?

Comment: @Serpiton, thanks! Now rolled back to QTP (need some urgent testing), as soon as I will use UFT again I can  tell you my researches.

Comment: @Serpiton, your idea would be right if UFT is used with connection to ALM. I'm using it as a separate tool, test is run directly from UFT (or by vbscript) and stored in test's directory. There should not be any permission problems (QTP run results viewer opens results this way)

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried to save the result file in a different folder, maybe one that doesn't begin with an underscore? Have you also tried to execute the Result Viewer with administrative rights?

Comment: @Serpiton, tried this right now. Move ResXX file to root dir, run Viewer as administrator. Result is the same. Do you use 12.52? Is it working fine?

Comment: I'm using UFT 12.02, I had a similar problem when I upgraded from QTP 10.00 to UFT 12.02, and solved it running the installation of the Viewed as Administrator. If I was you I'll open a support ticket with HP

Comment: @Serpiton, I've got the solution! May be it's right for 12.02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run results of UFT 12.52 tests could be opened in web browser, just click on the file:

```
run_results.html
```

Run results of UFT 12.52 test opened in Firefox:

[image]

And if you prefer to view results in `Run Results Viewer` there is a possibility to select in `Tools --> Options...`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solved !**

The workaround for your problem is:

1. Click on Tools/Options
2. Unselect "View results when run session ends"
3. Unselect "HTML Report"
4. Select "Run Results Viewer Report"
5. Click OK.

You can now view your reports.